# Maven: adding dependency for compiling tests, but NOT for running the test

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a complex case, where a Java TestNG test executed by Maven should have certain dependencies during compilation time only, but NOT during test execution. 
(To be short: **by its design**, the test case has to adjust class loading, and pick up certain JAR files at runtime).

Based on what I know about Gradle, it should be possible to achieve this (have certain dependencies at test compile, but not for test runtime).

I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the same in Maven?

Comment: I would expect that you could use compile or provided scope on your test dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To have something at compile time but not at runtime, you use the `provided` scope (or the `optional` scope, depending on the exact semantic) in Maven.